# Redirect .htaccess 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am migrating an entire webapp which contains a very big data stored in it.
I need to put on line the new server, but all the files are still passing through rsync.
I guess that process will take a lot of days.

I need to redirect the urls of some types of files (.pdf, .doc) that have not passed yet to the new server but exists in the old server.

Eg:
OLD SERVER X:   xxx.xx.xxx/data/30/document.pdf
NEW SERVER Y:   (not exists yet and show ERROR 404, but if exists show here:  yyy.yy.yyy/data/document.pdf)

I have read I can do this with a 301 redirection in .htacces but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer by my self...

All I had to do was create a .htacces inside de directory where the files are.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ http://oldserver.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Then in the httpd.conf in the  AllowOverride All.

It worked, I hope this would be usefull.

Thanks